# Issue installing ElementaryOS 5.1 Stable on Satellite Pro R40-c

Tags: ubuntu, install, error

Issue: USB and CDROM both fail with validation error for EOS5.1 Stable

Have downloaded iso file and tried as per your instructions.
SHA value is correct
Used UNetbootin & UUBytesISOEditor to create boot USB. Both show same issue on boot. Security Violation Error and ends with a blue sceen. Not BSOD
I formatted the USB before each attempt. Space is not an issue. Formatted both ExFAT and FAT32
Also burnt Ubuntu iso file same way on same USB (clean each time) - That works.
Did notice that the USB burn seems to hang for quite a while on filesystem.squashfs write to the USB

Appreciate any help. install Ubuntu but when try to install clean ElementaryOS - it fails on USB iinstall boot

PS Cannot include Violation in the Tags below. So including it here